# Use network scanner (from HP multifunction) in Kubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu, kde, scanner

In Ubuntu and Mint I used xsane to connect to my networked (wired ethernet) HP L7680 multifunction printer/scanner.

The default scanning app Skanlite in Kubuntu 12.04 won't find my device.

I like xsane and I am considering installing it, but it will bring in gimp and 62.9 MB of additional stuff.

Can anyone recommend the best way to scan stuff from my networked HP L7680 in Kubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with xsane. I just ran hp-setup from the command line, then started xsane and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. Note: you have to run hp-setup with sudo to enable the installation of propriatary HP drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to scan many documents and do not like mess with GUI, you can also use HP's command line utility like:

```
hp-scan -mcolor -r200 --output=my-document.png
```

For more options see

```
man hp-scan
```

Installation with

```
sudo apt-get install hplip
```